# Laravel validation response JSON returning extra array level

Tags: php, json, laravel, response

In my controller, I have this:

```
$validation = Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules);
if ($validation->fails())
{
    return Response::json($validation->errors());
}
```

and when i preview my view it doesn't print out anything but in debugger I see a json like this returned, so it's there.

```
{"username":["The username must be at least 6 characters."]}
username: ["The username must be at least 6 characters."]
0: "The username must be at least 6 characters."
```

I think it is making an extra level and puuting an array inside of an array, so my javascript is having trouble printing the inner contents:

```
0: The username must be at least 6 characters."
```

How can I make the return JSON object like this, getting rid of the extra top level:

```
username: ["The username must be at least 6 characters."]
0: "The username must be at least 6 characters."
```

Comment: instead of return Response::json simply return $your_array;

Comment: okay a random minus sign comes in and i tthink that is screwing up the printing. It comes like this                                                                             -username: ["The username must be at least 6 characters."]
0: "The username must be at least 6 characters." Why is there a random "-" returning